# Fail on Testing IntegrityError UNIQUE constraint

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-models

I have a unique_together constraint for email and store. I have used the following code to test the unique constraint. I'm expecting to pass the test with assertRaise but the result shows the opposite. What I'm missing here?

```
from django.db.backends.sqlite3.base import IntegrityError

class TestUserModel(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.store1 = Store.objects.create(name='store1')
        self.store2 = Store.objects.create(name='store2')

    def multiple_user_with_same_email_and_store(self):
        data1 = dict(email="abcd@gmail.com", password="a", store=self.store1)
        data2 = dict(email="abcd@gmail.com", password="abc", store=self.store1)
        self.user1 = User.objects.create(**data1)
        user2 = User(**data2)
        self.assertRaises(IntegrityError, user2.save)
```

Traceback

```
    Creating test database for alias 'default'...
E
======================================================================
ERROR: multiple_user_with_same_email_and_store (user.tests.test_models.TestUserModel)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ram/nk/project/helper/helper/user/tests/test_models.py", line 25, in multiple_user_with_same_email_and_store
    self.assertRaises(IntegrityError, user2.save)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/case.py", line 473, in assertRaises
    callableObj(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ram/.virtual/helper/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 734, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/home/ram/.virtual/helper/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 762, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/home/ram/.virtual/helper/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 846, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "/home/ram/.virtual/helper/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 885, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/home/ram/.virtual/helper/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 127, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ram/.virtual/helper/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 920, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/home/ram/.virtual/helper/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 974, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/ram/.virtual/helper/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/ram/.virtual/helper/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 97, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/home/ram/.virtual/helper/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/ram/.virtual/helper/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 318, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: user_user.email, user_user.store_id


    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Ran 1 test in 0.003s

    FAILED (errors=1)
```

User model extends AbstractUser (nothing other added at User), which is as follow

```
class AbstractUser(auth_models.AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'))
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store, verbose_name=_('Store Name'), null=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(_('First name'), max_length=255, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('Last name'), max_length=255, blank=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(
            _('Staff status'), default=False,
            help_text=_('Designates whether the user can log into this admin '
                        'site.'))
    is_active = models.BooleanField(
            _('Active'), default=True,
            help_text=_('Designates whether this user should be treated as '
                        'active. Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.'))
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'),
                                       default=timezone.now)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['store']

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        verbose_name = _('User')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Users')
        unique_together = ('email', 'store')
```

and UserManager

```
class UserManager(auth_models.BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, store, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email and
        password.
        """
        now = timezone.now()
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        email = UserManager.normalize_email(email)
        try:
            with transaction.atomic():
                store, created = Store.objects.get_or_create(name=store)
                user = self.model(email=email, store=store, is_staff=False, is_active=True, is_superuser=False,
                        last_login=now, date_joined=now, **extra_fields)
                user.set_password(password)
                user.save(using=self._db)
        except Error as e:
            logging.ERROR(e)
            raise Error("Internal Error: Unable to create user")
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, store, email, password, **extra_fields):
        u = self.create_user(store, email, password, **extra_fields)
        u.is_staff = True
        u.is_active = True
        u.is_superuser = True
        u.save(using=self._db)
        return u

    def create_staffuser(self, store, email, password, **extra_fields):
        u = self.create_user(store, email, password, **extra_fields)
        u.is_staff = True
        u.is_active = True
        u.is_superuser = False
        u.save(using=self._db)
        return u
```

Version: 1.8

Comment: could you please show your `User` model's definition (fields and if there is, the __init__ method) as well as the full error stack trace

Comment: unique_together should be a tuple of tuples (in this case, it checks that email is unique in itself AND store is unique in itself), see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.unique_together but it doesn't explain why it isn't failing on the line expected (though here the full error traceback would help)

Comment: in the test, where is `IntegrityError` imported from?

Comment: I suspect some kind of wrapper (django.db.utils.IntegrityError) or import mixup, and would debug that using `self.assertRaises` as a context manager - `with self.assertRaises(Exception) as raised: user2.save()` followed by `self.assertEqual(IntegrityError, type(raised.exception))`

Comment: the type interesting is not `raised` but `raised.exception` and it's `self.assertEqual(In‌​tegrityError, type(raised.exceptio‌​n))` not `self.assertEqual(In‌​tegrityError, raised.exception)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So the error is being raised at the right line (in `assertRaises`), but I suspect there are two different kinds of `IntegrityError` classes at play here - one that is imported by the test, and one that is raised by the database backend.

e.g.: `django.db.backends.postgresql.base.IntegrityError` is not the same as `django.db.backends.sqlite3.base.IntegrityError`. On top of that, there is the Django exception wrapper `django.db.utils.IntegrityError`

The issue can be debugged and verified by using `self.assertRaises` as a context manager:

```
with self.assertRaises(Exception) as raised:  # top level exception as we want to figure out its exact type
    user2.save()
self.assertEqual(IntegrityError, type(raised.exception))  # if it fails, we'll get the correct type to import
```